# schema generation for IBM Graph using Node-js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, formatting

I would like to dynamically generate the following kind of json object from a set of arrays but am having trouble with generating the specific format for the propertyKeys

Required format:

```
vertexIndexes":[{"name":"vByName","propertyKeys":["name"],"composite":true,"unique":true}]
```

Comment: Be more specific , in propertyKeys.name , which are the possible values that this property can take ? What kind of graph is that ? In which format you get the info for the vertices ?

Comment: you could have a look at it below

https://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/interactive-guide-node-js.html